# PyCharm is missing project type drop down

Tags: python, pycharm

I've just downloaded PyCharm community edition for my Mac. It seems to work great but for some reason project type -dropdown is missing in Create project dialog. I'm newbie to PyCharm (and Python overall) so I don't know if there is some obvious reason for this.

I was able to create projects however - even in virtualenv. But they are always empty projects.

Comment: Looking further into it I found that this feature seems to be available only in Professional version

Comment: Dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25064360/google-appengine-project-in-pycharm

Answer (score 3):

This may be due to Community Edition which doesn't provide all functionality. Download the professional edition of pycharm. The professional edition is free to use for one month.