# Google AppEngine Project in PyCharm

Tags: google-app-engine, pycharm

I am following the instructions at http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/quickstart/appengine_guide.html to create a GAE project in PyCharm. When I click on New Project, I don't see the "project type" drop down box:

[image]

Do I need to set some configuration or environment variable so that PyCharm can find my GAE SDK installation?

Comment: Which version are you using? I've using 3.4 Professional and I get the project type dialogue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is likely because you are using the community edition which does not support GAE or any web framework for that matter.